# Delphi - Displaying All Image Format

Tags: delphi, image

Im a newbie programmer in Delphi. I need help, I have a small project which I need to display all kind of image format.

Please suggest what should I do or any component in delphi that support all image format? thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a Library that suites my need. It called [vampyre library](http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/) and works amazing. It support TIFF,tif, animating gif and many more

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33) library available from [www.soft-gems.net](http://www.soft-gems.net). This should give you most (if not all) of the formats you want.

Comment: You beat me with seconds... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use several image types with the standard TImage component. At least bmp and jpg (if you use the Jpeg unit).

Version 2009 added some more. Image formats (I thought at least png and wmf).

There are a lot of third party components for image display/processing. A google search will show them all.

Comment: i am using delphi 7. jpg, gif, png and other default format on TImage is no problem to me. but dealing with tif, tiff format. TImage cant support those kind of format. I look up on google on 3rd party component but i cant find the right component i need. Any suggestion??thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

[GraphicEx](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33#GraphicEx) should be a good start. It's free and contains the most used formats.

Answer (score 1):

Both  [ImageEn](http://www.hi-components.com/nimageen.asp)  and [Imaging Toolkit for Delphi](http://www.mcm-design.com/index.php?section=products&product=ImagingDelphi) offer wide range of supported format

and you can find more in [torry](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=112) site